# Doubt in calculating $\sqrt {-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is regarding a doubt in contour integration [example 1 - at time 4.49 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnSrxgRjwJU&list=PL6viIjeqW6oNN3wTFQMJ9Vzps1kPzkiF3&index=5]. I did all the problem. I need to find the value of residue. This is found as $\dfrac{\sqrt {-i}}{-2i}$

> $-i = e^{\frac{-i\pi}{2}}\tag{1}$
>
> $-i = e^{\frac{i3\pi}{2}}\tag{2}$

Using $(1)$, $\text{value of residue} = \dfrac{e^{\frac{-i\pi}{4}}}{-2i} = \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{4}+\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{4}i\tag{3}$

Using $(2)$, $\text{value of residue} = \dfrac{e^{\frac{i3\pi}{4}}}{-2i} = -\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{4}-\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{4}i\tag{4}$

Due to this, my residue sum changed. But when I saw the solution of problem, **he took  $-i$ as $(2)$ instead of $(1)$**

But $-i$ is negative $y-$axis. The answer should come same. But it is differing. I am not able to understand here. Pls, explain.

[image]

Comment: You should post the integral to be computed and the contour as the choice of the appropriate root depends on that.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net kindly see 1st example in video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnSrxgRjwJU&list=PL6viIjeqW6oNN3wTFQMJ9Vzps1kPzkiF3&index=5 at time 4.49

Comment: Could you please post the integral and relevant contour inside your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He has taken $-i$ as $(2)$ because of where his branch cut is placed.

In order to calculate the real integral $\int^\infty_0f(x)dx$ he has used what he calls the "Pac Man contour". This contour places a cut along the positive $x$-axis. He has effectively restricted himself to using $\{0<\mathrm{arg}(z)<2\pi\}$.

If his "Pac Man contour" had been the other way around, with the cut along the negative $x$-axis (in order, for example, to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^0f(x)dx$) then he would use $\{-\pi<\mathrm{arg}(z)<\pi\}$ and would take $-i$ as $(1)$.

I would recommend reading more about branch cuts and why they are necessary.

Comment: @E Malkin Ok as he is travelling in counterclock wise direction to reach branch cut it should be $3\pi/2$ instead of $-\pi/2$ right? (before reaching branch cut right?)....

Comment: Actually in my university previous year exam papers, branch cut Qns are asked. But in my textbook there is no topic related to branch cuts. So i search google, youtube and found this video. Can you pls suggest me some good book which is easy to understand...

Comment: or Sir can u pls explain me precisely here itself? this topic only....

Comment: Yes, you are correct: he has travelled counterclockwise. I would very much recommend _Introduction to Complex Analysis_ by H. A. Priestly, for her explanation of branch cuts and of the rest of the topic.

Comment: Tq..............